# How to pass array from Twig to Javascript using JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, symfony, twig, symfony4

I need your help to work miracles.

I want to convert Twig array to Javascript array and then use it in a loop and create markers for the Google API.

```
<script>
    var map, marker, i, e;
    var companies = {{ companies.items | json_encode() | raw }};

    console.log(companies);
    var address = {{ search.city.first.name | json_encode() | raw }};

    function initMap() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 44.8333, lng: -0.5667},
            zoom: 12,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        });

        //for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            //marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                //position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                //map: map
            //});

    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEYLOL&callback=initMap"></script>
```

When I get my array back, companies show me an empty array.

[image: Screen of empty array of console.log(companies)]

But when I dump this on twig my array is ok ..

[image: Dump array on Twig]

Can someone help me?

Comment: [This symfony doc explains how](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/server-data.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put all my values into a hidden input. And I get it in json at last I `JSON.parse` my Json result. It's not perfect but it's working.

My Twig code :

```
{% set array = [] %}
  {% for company in companies %}
    {% set array = array | merge([{name: company.title, latitude: company.latitude, longitude: company.longitude}]) %}
  {% endfor %}
  <input type="hidden" id="array" value="{{ array|json_encode }}">
```

My javascript :

```
<script>
    var map, marker, i;
    var array = document.getElementById('array').value;
    var companies = JSON.parse(array);

    var address = {{ search.city.first.name | json_encode() | raw }};

    function initMap() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 44.8333, lng: -0.5667},
            zoom: 14,
        });

        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });

        for (i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(companies[i].latitude, companies[i].longitude),
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(companies[i].name);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't forget you could just create a jascript variable in your `twig` template instead of using the hidden input `var address = {{ { 'name': company.title, 'latitude': company.latitude, 'longitude': company.longitude, } | json_encode }}`. This variable will be accessible in your external JS files

Answer (score 2):

`json_encode` will by default serialize an object by outputting all public (i.e. accessible) properties. Since your objects have no public properties, the serialization is empty. you could implement the [`JsonSerializable`](https://php.net/JsonSerializable) interface. (IMHO, the simplest solution)

There are other more complicated ways to achieve this. They become relevant if the json serialization will vary on context .... Alternatives would be to implement a twig function that will fetch certain fields from your objects, writing a proper serializer or implementing functions on your objects that expose the proper serialization depending on context.